# How to escape @ character in ASP.NET Razor

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have tried the methods provided, using `<text></text>` using double at the rate icons as `@@`. But doesn't work.

My issue or my code is like this:

```
<li id="@">@</li>
```

I am creating a keyboard plugin, so I need `@` sign to be there for the user, but when I write this, it starts a razor block and give me error that `""></li>"` is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, `(` and `{` are valid.

```
<li id="@@">@@</li>
```

This didn't work either, as I have mentioned in the first row of my question.

What might be a good idea, to escape this, the issue is with the `@` inside the qoutes only the one that will be shown is OK (the one inside the list).

Comment: try <li id="@:@@">@:@@</li>

Comment: Nope same, this time it tells me that `:` is not a valid start ..

Comment: Just @@ should do it, e.g. <li id="@@">@@</li>

Comment: I have told in the question, that I have tried using `double qoutes` too, as it was an answer from other post on stackoverflow. But doesn't work for me..

Comment: how about <li id="@("@")">@("@")</li>

Comment: Not really, just googled and hacked about in visual studio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try and escape `@("@")` with

```
<li id="@("@")">@("@")</li>
```

Comment: have a plus one, however I was not able to take this trick! :D is there a js way to do this?

Comment: because lets say, PHP, what to do in that? PHP won't read @ .. can I handle this in JS?

Comment: Why don't you start a new question with as much code as you can provide or even a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) explaining what you are trying to do and one of the javascript experts will help

Comment: Ok, wait! Should I edit this questions? because new question might get closed or get duplicate tag, wait!

Comment: I think we have answered the question you asked and it may help someone else so should be left here. Your problem is something different, I think it justifies a new question.

Comment: @Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan - if the answer helped you, you can help others too: [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackoverflow)